# TikZ-subfigures are not horizontally aligned

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, align, subfloats

I have tried to align two tikz-subfigures. For for some reason though it doesn't work completely and they are misaligned horizontally as per this screenshot.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.98\linewidth}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          scaled y ticks = false,
          y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
        ]

        \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
            (1, 1)
            (2, 2)
            (3, 3)
            (4, 4)
            (5, 5)
            (6, 6)
            (7, 7)
            (8, 8)
          };
      \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \\[5mm]
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          scaled y ticks = false,
          y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
        ]

        \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
            (-100, -1)
            (200, 2)
            (300, 3)
          };
      \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}  %
  \caption{asd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Replace `\\ \vspace{5mm}` by `\\[5mm]`.

Comment: @dexteritas I made the change and it worked. But I then made some changes to the input-data, and then it stopped working (see the updated OP) - can you spot why?

Comment: See my first comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691966/align-tikzpicture-plots-subfigures-horizontally-and-vertically about the causes, and a fine solution by another member of this community.

Answer (score 1):

You must expand the width assigned to the y-labels (in both plots) to accommodate the minus sign.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup{width=.98\linewidth}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \pgfplotsset{yticklabel style = {text width=2.5em, align=right}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<        
        
        \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                scaled y ticks = false,
                y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                ]
                
                \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
                    (1, 1)
                    (2, 2)
                    (3, 3)
                    (4, 4)
                    (5, 5)
                    (6, 6)
                    (7, 7)
                    (8, 8)
                };
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\[5mm]
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}%
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                scaled y ticks = false,
                y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill, /pgf/number format/precision=2},
                ]
                
                \addplot[color=black] coordinates {
                    (-100, -1)
                    (200, 2)
                    (300, 3)
                };
            \end{axis}
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}  %
    \caption{asd}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using `\centering` and your plots are not precisely the same width: the minus sign in the bottom figure makes it just slightly wider. It is almost but not quite perfectly lined up if I put `\phantom{+}` right before the first `tikzpicture` environment, and you could replace that or augment it with `\hspace` commands to get it to line up perfectly by hand.